# Activities and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's the deal, i have a simple application in which u user will log in and view reports.
My basic architecture of these reports consists of a header fragment which will display user login info, then a table layout which will hold the report content and a footer fragment in which i have created an option menu for all the report i will be providing.
Now, i have different activities for each report and i start/launch these activites from the **onOptionsItemSelected()** as follows:

`getActivity().startActivity(intent);`

The first report, menu and all its items load perfectly.
But when i select a menu item from the menu my app stops giving the following exception:

```
04-04 18:29:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(1123): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Report2}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
```

I am guessing that this is happening because the next activity also contains those fragments(header and footer).
Is my approach wrong? I am looking up on the net, but loads of info leaves me confused at the end. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT : **

layout XML for report 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.HeaderFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:layout="@layout/header_fragment" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tblSummRep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:padding="5dip">

    </TableLayout>
    <fragment
        android:name="com.example.FooterFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:layout="@layout/footer_fragment" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

the above layout will be same for all reports

the code for routing the menu itmes(in the class for footer fragment) is as follows :

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        int switchTo = mm.routeMenu(item, con);
        switch (switchTo) {
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(con, Report2.class);
            isAct = "Y";
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(con, Report3.class);
            isAct = "Y";
            break;
        case 4:
            intent = new Intent(con, Report4.class);
            isAct = "Y";
            break;
        case 5:
            intent = new Intent(con, Report5.class);
            isAct = "Y";
            break;
        case 6:
            intent = new Intent(con, Report6.class);
            isAct = "Y";
            break;
        default:
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        if(isAct.toUpperCase().equals("Y")){
            if(Login.lstLogin != null){
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**mm.RouteMenu()** is in in a different class which handles things like fetching the items to be diplayed from the database.

Also, **con** is `activity.getApplicationContext();` which is in the **onAttach()** event

Comment: Could you post the layout xml? It can be a number of different things. But most likely, the next activity has an invalid name/class for the fragment e.g. <fragment class="wrong.package.Report2" >

Comment: Could you post some minimal code for your `Fragment`?

Comment: the error says there is something wrong while inflating the xml. check for the references you are creating in the onCreateView of the fragment. Some view id might be mismatched or it might not exist.